# Pass Class in Scala as param

Tags: scala, playframework

we are in a process of migrating one java based project to java-scala based project. To do that we are using JPA Hibernate in scala with play framework. As a part of DB operation I want a write an generic method in scala which can run createQuery with any any object.

```
entityManager.createQuery("From Buddy", classOf[Buddy]).getResultList.toList
```

To make this generic method , I have to pass this class "Buddy" or anything it may be as a param in the method. Can any one suggest how to do that?

My requirement is that , I want to pass query as sting along with class which I can use directly or doing some sort of reflection in "classOf" in my generic method. So that method we can use for any query with any object. 
Any help will be appropriated , I have the same implementation in java. In java it was easy to implement with class object and again re create the object with new instance.  Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated...

Comment: This is the wrong generalization to use with ORM, which exists solely to provide a type safe and object-oriented view of the DB. Running random queries by concatenation of strings was a thing in the early 2000, not anymore, not to mention the risk of SQL injection. You wouldn't need to pass in classes if you define specific entities for your purpose.

Comment: can you please elaborate you comment. In such a scenario what will be the actual solution?

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar this was the default way of working with JPA in Play 1.x .. its a legit question to ask.